# Should I reshuffle the training set when benchmarking neural networks?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, data, training, research

I'm trying to set up a fair benchmarking between various RNN models, where each of them is trained until convergence with a fixed random seed. Because the task is very costly, I am only able to run each model once and then compare their performance.

By reshuffling training set, I would change the loss surface every epoch. The result is that the models converge to a more generalized minima. But assumed that my random seed is fixed and the training time per epoch for each model is not equal, every model would be trained with a different set of permutations of the training set. I'm worried that this discrepancy would affect the fairness of the benchmark?

Without reshuffled training data set, however, I would not know if my fixed seed would bias some models over others.

My question is: assume that I want to run each model once, and to keep the result to be comparatively fair, is it a good idea to reshuffle the training set every epoch?

Comment: Yes. Even for normal training, (not for benchmarking) you have to reshuffle your data for every new epoch. The reason being - your model will learn not the content of the data, but the pattern of what sample comes after the current one. It simply overfits on that. That will make your model to fail in real scenario. In your specific case though, shuffling will not save you from a flawed result. Initialization greatly affects your model performance. Hence, you can't really rely on a single run. I normally average results over 5 or 10 runs and report that. The more the better.